# Can feature questions improve the site's visibility?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I was recently looking at the unanswered questions, and decided to give one of them a bounty (I didn't really think about why I chose that one, frankly the silliest of them all... It just looked easy enough to generate a rapid response and leave the unanswered list). I see other stacks have plenty of bounties going on, while we have plenty of unsolved questions that could benefit from them (some that have many visits are [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/help-docs-for-using-inkscape-for-svg-icon-font-creation) and [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7366/create-rounded-button-with-embossed-edge-inner-shadow-and-engraved-text)).

Should we encourage featured questions, and maybe also create some using what some of us find difficult to resolve to go in this list?

Comment: What was the question you gave a bounty to, and did it help?

Comment: It didn't help because I chose the lamest question ever, but I wouldn't mind trying with a new one.

Comment: Ha! :) I really want to know what this question is now...

Comment: no. not relevant. nooooooo